# Getting the UUID from a new IBeacon

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, core-bluetooth

I've bought a cheap IBeacon just for testing purposes, but i can't seem to find the UUID, i've tried below but does not seem to be called?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!){
    print("test: \(beacons[0].proximityUUID.UUIDString)")

}
```

Comment: what does it print ?

Comment: it doesnt print anything, seems like it isnt called

Comment: You need to know the UUID so that you can provide that to a CLBeaconRegion before you will, get any callbacks. Unfortunately you can't just listen for all beacons. Many beacons have BLE characteristics that are used to set the UUID, major and minor. Try the Light Blue Explorer app on the App Store